# Отсутствует префикс 'b в байтовой строке

Tags: python, строки

Есть строка https://github.com/yagust/ask_1, которая закодирована в base64(предположительно), при декодировании в байты нет префикса `b'` с чем может быть связано такое поведение? Код ниже использую для декодирования

```
import codecs
codecs.decode(string.encode(),"base64")
```

Comment: Префикс есть: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZndq.png Может там куда вы выводите просто количество строк в выводе ограничено, и начало вывода обрезается.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Действительно, часть вывода съедалось cmd